# Annoying differential equation involving composition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Upon trying to crack into a problem, I managed to end up with the following differential equation.
$$
y = xy' - y'\circ y', \qquad\text{or}\qquad y(x) = x\cdot y'(x) - y'(y'(x))
$$
I haven't a clue where to start when solving this. It's that darn $y'\circ y'$ term. I don't even know if there is a valid solution. Any ideas?

Comment: $y = x - 1$ seems to be a particular solution.

Comment: There are more solutions, eg. $y = \alpha(x-1)$ and $y = \left(\frac{x}{\phi}\right)^{\phi+1}$.